# Animating two objects when there's multiple actions

Tags: animation, objects

I'm rather new to Blender and I have created a character for a game.

This character needs to have several animations such as run, walk, idle etc. I have created an action for each of these animations in the Dope Sheet and it all has been working fine so far, but I recently ran into a problem.

In one of the animations the character is supposed to bring out a box out of thin air and place it on the ground. I created the box in a seperate file and then appended it into the characters file where I thought that I could simply decide during which action the box would show up, but I can't get it to work.

I can create a seperate action to animate the box within and follow along with the animation, and this does work. But when I change the action of the **character** from the correct animation over to idle for example. The box still shows up.

So I thought that if I went into each of the actions and keyframed the visibility of the box by pressing <kbd>I</kbd> while hovering over the eye icon that it would work. But if I keyframe the visibility of the box (while within an action for the character) it also affects the character itself. The box is not parented to the character.

To clarify my question: Is there way to only show one object during a specific action and NOT during any other ones? Or maybe there is another way to get around this problem?

Any help is appreciated!